# How can I view how many rows I have in each table in Windows Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Maybe I overlooked this in the Windows Azure Portal, but I can't find how many rows I currently have per table.

If I query for it, I assume a transaction cost will be incurred.  Is there a way to freely see how many records there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no aggregate operations on Windows Azure Table Storage that allow you to do this. The best you can do is to fetch all partition and/or row keys for a table and count them yourself. The second-best thing you can do is to implement a mechanism to count and persist this number in an external system in some way (whether that means simply counting the number of times you successfully insert vs delete, tracking all partition/row keys in SQL Server so you can count them, or something else).

Ultimately, if you need aggregate operations on large quantities of data, Table Storage is not the correct solution for you.